# How to get url for D3.json dynamically using input tag type=file?

Tags: javascript, json, html, d3.js

Am using D3.js to **input a json file** and graphically plot it.

Here's my js required:

```
function loadJSON(url) {
    d3.json("url", function(data) {
        dataProcessor(data);
    });
}
```

Here's my html required:

```
 <body>
        <div><h1>Chart 101</h1></div>
        <input id="source" type="file">
        <button id="clickHere" onclick="loadJSON()">CLick here</button>
        <script src="../js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/ChartFactory.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Bascially d3.json **requires the url of the file selected**.
Check [**here**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json)
But since mozilla **[doesnt allow the path to be visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)** using the "inputId.value",i cant seem to move forward with this.

Is there any solution or work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the file full path on client machine using browser and javascript. 
you have to upload file to server using form and then get the file.